Are UIs of video games subject to IP protection?
This applies to their layouts, colors, choices, etc. Does an infringement happen only when the UI elements are blatantly ripped off?

Relevant https://brainly.com/question/35297510

These are called "look and feel" infringement lawsuits and it is a muddy area. One of the earliest such suits unsuccessfully challenged the Windows UI for violating the MacOS UI's "look and feel" (or I may be remembering it wrong and it may instead have been a lawsuit related to the MasOS UI copying the the Xerox UI that inspired it).

Depends on the exact jurisdiction, the degree of similarity, and what was actually filed for protection.

Copyright can protect sentences and longer texts, images, and so on. It cannot protect individual words or colors.
Trademarks can protect words and even colors, but only in contexts where a mistake is possible.
Patents can protect technological innovations, but not scientific discoveries. Their use for software is problematic, leaving copyright to protect software.

The concept that an OK button gets rounded edges and the capital letters 'O' and 'K' on it cannot be copyrighted or trademarked. More complex designs can.
If your design has been 'blatantly ripped off,' talk to a lawyer who knows the precedents in your jurisdiction. If you are considering your own game, and you are close enough to someone else to ask this question, don't copy it.

There are lots of software patents in the US, and some of them are for UI elements. For example, I think the "rubber-band line" used in graphical editing was patented (this was back in the 70's or 80's so the patent has expired).

Note also that copyright is subject to significant limitations when the subject matter is somehow useful. In the US, this is codified at 17 USC 102(b), and see also prior case law Baker v. Selden.

Whether a specific UI infringes will be judged on a combination of factors, as it's pretty unavoidable that two UI's for the same goal will have some similarity.
Scène à faire is the legal doctrine which says that necessary elements of a work are not subject to copyright. So, for a game UI, the idea of an ammo counter would be considered non-copyrightable, but its exact representation ("blatant ripoff") is still protected. Putting that counter on the edge of the UI is similarly not protected - it's necessary to not block the players view. Color is more of a free choice, although accommodation for colorblind players adds a few restrictions.

Depends on your Jurisdiction
Most countries have very limited IP protections when it comes to UI design.  So, the answer to this is usually no, but there are a few caveats.
Patents
Most countries don't let you Patent UI elements at all, but Japan and to a lesser degree, the United States allow it.
Nintendo for example holds a large number of UI patents for the elements in their video games, but most of them are only enforceable in Japan.  So, if you sell a product that may be purchased internationally, you should be careful about selling in Japan.
That said, even in Japan, UI patents are pretty weak. More often than not, such patents are found to be obvious and anticipated or already matters of public domain when they go to trial; however, it is common for smaller companies to be bullied into settlements when they can not afford the legal cost of fighting them.
US patent law is even more limited.  It allows you to file for patents on UI, but it limits protection to the ornamental and graphical aspects of it; so, no matter how functionally novel and innovative your idea is, it's really easy to get around US patent law just by styling your UI differently: replacing circles with squares, changing color pallets and textures, etc.
Copyright
UI copyright cases are in many cases harder to defend against when they come up, but so narrow in scope that they rarely do.  Most countries consider UIs synonymous with artwork when it comes to how they evaluate IP cases; so, if your UI uses images and verbiage that are exactly copied from another source and not obvious and anticipated, it could be a copyright issue.  That said, copyright does nothing to stop another person from creating a nearly identical UI.  So unless their UI is a pixel perfect knockoff, it's usually not applicable.
The other way Copyright can come into play is if they stole your source code.  It is usually really hard to prove that someone is using stolen source code, but there have been cases where a game has used a modified visual front-end, but had the same bugs as the program they ripped off which is enough to sopenia their source code for a copyright suit.
Trade Dress
This can come up in cases where your program not only looks like another, but is actively designed to deceive users into believing that it is another program or made by the another company.  In this case, it takes more than just a similar UI to prove a Trade Dress violation, but it can become one of the factors that get assessed in a Trade Dress violation if they find that enough other stuff like packaging, logos, product names, etc. share enough similarity that your program as a whole could deceive normal and reasonable users into believing your program was made by the other company.

US patent 7844915B2 was for rubber band lines, a UI process.

@Barmar Rubber band lines are a rendering process, not a UI process.  UI processes are processes related to the interaction of a user with the program like menus, inputs, dropdowns, radios, checkboxes, etc.

It's a user interaction process -- the user drags the line around on the screen. Yes, it includes the rendering part that involves XORing.

Sorry, there is a similar term used in graphics rendering describing how pixels are redrawn.  That said, the US has also gone through a complicated history with patenting software.  In the 60-80s it was common to get patents, but in the early 90s there was a series of important court cases that pretty much invalided all use cases for patents for software under US law.  Every patent case you see after that for years was either dismissed or settled.  It's only been in the past few years that new laws have made software patents a meaningful thing in the US again.

Didn't know about that change. I suspect it was due to the rise of patent trolls in the software industry. And lots of things that many practicioners considered obvious were getting patents granted.

@Barmar It had more to do with the laws not being written with software in mind.  The law said that products could be patented but processes could not becaused in the Industrial age, they wanted to make sure that a competitor was still free to design a better product to perform the same process as a patented product without being blocked by patent law, but the argument was made that programs are proccessess, not products; so, for nearly 20 years, American software patents were typically rejected and never enforced because they violated the process exemption.

Design patents, which is what you're referring to in ornamental UI elements, aren't limited to the US and Japan: they just go under the different name of design rights. For example, the EU has unified them under the name community design.
